# Can't get overridden method to execute

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have parent classes defined as follows:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class GameState
    {
        public Player ThisPlayer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Player(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public void TakeTurn(GameState state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Models.Player.TakeTurn");
        }
    }
}
```

Sub-classes defined as:

```
namespace Subs
{
    public class GameState : Models.GameState
    {
        public void TakeTurn()
        {
            ThisPlayer.TakeTurn(this);
        }
    }

    public class Player : Models.Player
    {
        public Player(int id) : base(id) { }

        public virtual void TakeTurn(GameState state)
        {
            base.TakeTurn(state);
            Console.WriteLine("In Subs.Player.TakeTurn");
        }
    }

    public class MachinePlayer : Player
    {
        public MachinePlayer(int id) : base(id) { }

        public override void TakeTurn(GameState state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Subs.MachinePlayer.TakeTurn");
        }
    }
}
```

Program has:

```
Subs.MachinePlayer machinePlayer = new Subs.MachinePlayer(1);
Subs.GameState state = new Subs.GameState();
state.ThisPlayer = machinePlayer;
state.TakeTurn();
```

The problem is even though the player is a MachinePlayer, the MachinePlayer TakeTurn method is never executed and the output is just:

```
In Models.Player.TakeTurn
```

I want each player to take a turn.  Some players are human (Subs.Player) or bots (Subs.MachinePlayer).  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: `TakeTurn` method in `Models.Player` isn't a `virtual` and doesn't overridden anywhere

Comment: You know you have two classes called Player, right? That's really confusing

Comment: I updated the example to make the method virtual and to rename the sub-classes.  Now it's telling me it can't find a method to override.  I realize the signature must match exactly, but then I won't be able to access the SubGameState methods.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please roll back your edit on the question. It's completely different now and invalidates the answers given. That's not what edits are for. Ask a new question for your new problem and upvote/accept an answer if it explained your problem

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have two methods in the inherited class named `TakeTurn` (two overloads):

```
public void TakeTurn(Models.GameState state); // Models.Player
public override void TakeTurn(Subs.GameState state); // Subs.Player
```

Notice the types of the arguments. When you do this:

```
ThisPlayer.TakeTurn(this);
```

You are *really* doing this:

```
((Models.Player)ThisPlayer).TakeTurn((Models.GameState)this);
```

Why? Because the **static type** of `ThisPlayer` is `Models.Player` which only has the single (first) method that itself is **not `virtual`**. There's no overload resolution or virtual dispatch. The **only** candidate is the one declared on the base class.

Verify this with [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) by looking at the IL:

```
method public hidebysig 
    instance void TakeTurn () cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance class Models.Player Models.GameState::get_ThisPlayer()
    IL_0006: ldarg.0
    IL_0007: callvirt instance void Models.Player::TakeTurn(class Models.GameState) // <-- HERE
    IL_000c: ret
}
```

What do I suggest? First name your classes a bit better (two classes with the same name in different namespace is **very** confusing). Then, make the method in the base class `virtual` and fix the derived classes' overriden methods so that they use the proper parameter type (same as the base class).

Comment: I changed the SubsPlayer and MachinePlayer method signatures to:  public override void TakeTurn(Models.GameState state)  That means I need to cast the state parameter as SubsGameState if I want to access a property or method in SubsGameState.  I can live with that unless someone can think of a better approach.

Comment: You're basically violating LSP in that case. Your option is to type check and cast if you really need it. You could   get it with some generics gymnastics but it's overkill IMO and without seeing your full usage I can't really suggest that. A new question would be appropriate. I answered your original question, you can't change it and make it something completely different

Answer (score 0):

Player take turn method is not virtual you need to change that and it should work. Also override where needed as well.